# Can't get django model form to pass information to database

Tags: django, django-forms

I’m trying to post data from my django model form to my database, but am not having any luck. I can create from the admin and display on the page, but can’t seem to pass my information correctly. The comment is linked to the school with a foreign key, which I know works. Here’s what I have for my models, views, and html.

**models.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Comment(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(Schools)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['author', 'body', 'school']
```

**views.py**

**EDITED**

I also added the comment object create, just as another thing to try.

```
from my_app.models import Comment, CommentForm

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        author = form.cleaned_data['author']
        body = form.cleaned_data['body']
        school = form.cleaned_data['school']
        form.save()
        content = Comment.objects.create(school = school, author = author, body = body)
```

I have tried many variations on this view, but have not had any luck yet.

**html**

```
<form action="/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     <p>{{ form.body }}</p>
     <div id="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A. You must specify either `{{form.as_p}}`, `{{form.as_table}}` or simply `{{form}}` instead of `{{form.body}}`. Check the docs for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

B. The `cleaned_data` require an attribute from the `Comment` class. So, change: `body = form.cleaned_data['comment']` with `body = form.cleaned_data['body']`

C. Have fun with Django.

**Edit**

Move the `if request.method == 'POST':` inside a new method, i.e. `register_comment`:

```
def register_comment:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            author = form.cleaned_data['author']
            body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            school = form.cleaned_data['school']
            form.save()
```

Modify the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatters = patterns('',
    # Some others views here
    url(r'^new-comment/$', 'app_name.views.register_comment', name="new_comment"),
    # Maybe Some others views here
)
```

Open your web browser, and go to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/new-comment/`

Comment: I've changed what you said I ought to, but still to no avail... I'm editing above to show what I changed.